# update ckeditor and integrate it with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, ckeditor, fckeditor

I was working with an old version of ckeditor (fckeditor 2.x) integrated in a java project with jsp and struts framework.
Now I need to update the project with a new version of ckeditor. I've tried to do it as stated in the documentation [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Integration) but is not working as it should.

I've downloaded the most recent ckeditor and placed it in the web application directory, then I downloaded the jar file, placed it in WEB-INF/lib folder and add it to the project on eclipse.

In the jsp file I'm adding:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>
```

and then in the body I'm trying to something close to this: (inside a "multipart/form-data" form)

```
<td class="cellcontent">
     <bean:define id="propertyValueId" name="formName" property="example" />
    <ckeditor:editor instanceName="example" toolbarSet="Default" height="200px">
        <jsp:attribute name="value">
            <c:out value="${propertyValueId}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
        </jsp:attribute>
    </ckeditor:editor>                                                      
</td>
```

This is exactly the way I used to do, and IT IS WORKING PROPERLY with the version 2.x. As some properties are not accepted anymore, I've tried something like this.

```
<td class="cellcontent">
    <bean:define id="propertyValueId" name="formName" property="example" />
    <ckeditor:editor basePath="/ckeditor/" editor="content"  >
        <jsp:attribute name="value">
            <c:out value="${propertyValueId}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
        </jsp:attribute>
    </ckeditor:editor>
</td>
```

I've tried the simple example below, and the the output still a normal text area.

```
<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>               
<ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="/ckeditor/" />
```

I guess I'm forgetting something on configs or just some tags missing in the jsp, I've already googled it and read every question here, but I can't figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already find the answer. For anyone interested, it is just simple as this with the new version ok ckeditor:

```
<ckeditor:editor basePath="<%=ckeditor_context %>" editor="content" />

<tr>
    <td class="celltitle">
        <strong>Example1 </strong>
    </td>
    <td class="cellcontent">
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="example1"></textarea>                                                  
    </td>
</tr>
```

(...)

```
<tr>
    <td class="celltitle">
        <strong>Example2 </strong>
    </td>
    <td class="cellcontent">
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="example2"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is on the basePath tag. It should point to your ckeditor.js location properly.